# Trying to exit a method, using return, but doesn't actually return anything

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using `return EXIT_SUCCESS` to exit a void function. However I get a flag that says my method should not return a value.

The code works fine, but is there a better way to exit a method by using a return or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine the method as

```
-(int)myMethod;
```

Then you can return EXIT_SUCCESS.

Is any code calling this method and expecting a value?

Answer (score 7):

To add to the other answers, you can always return from a void function with `return;`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand how functions work. When you specify the prototype as`void` you are saying the function won't return anything. You are then contradicting the prototype by trying to return something. Change the prototype to `-(int)function` to return EXIT_SUCCESS. If you do not want to return something, but want to still check if it was successful you could pass in a pointer to the function: `-(void)functionReturnValue:int* returnValue`. Make the function set returnValue to EXIT_SUCCESS on successful completion and have the calling function check returnValue.

Comment: You are talking about functions but your examples show methods.

Comment: @Till I wasn't aware there was a difference. What's the difference between functions and methods?